# Star of the Allies

Tags: europe, world-war-one, flags

Which alliance is this?

The picture is from a hand stitched post card around the time of WWI. Can't figure out when these five nations (assuming the black/yellow is some form of Germany), would have been allied together in that time period.

[image]

Comment: The picture is sideways. Could you please rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: Clockwise from top of star: France, Belgium, Russia, Italy & Great Britain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clockwise from the top of the star (left side of the picture) -
[France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France),
[Belgium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Belgium),
[Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Russia),
[Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Italy),
[UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom)

Which corresponds to the major Allied Powers in WW1 before the entry of the United States and the exit of Russia. The Russian Symbol is a bit hard to identify, but it was probably chosen to differentiate [the Flag of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Russia) from the French Tricolor, since the orientations of the flags seem variable for this card.

Comment: Ah yes, on rotation, its clear that the Gold and Black Flag is the Russian Double-Headed Eagle.

Answer (score 0):

The nations in question would appear to be (clockwise from the "S" in "Star") Italy, the United Kingdom, France, Belgium, and (edit: Russia). The Russian symbol is based on the [Imperial Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Imperial_Standards), rather than the national flag, because the national flag had the same colours as France.

The colours of WWI Germany were black, white and red, rather than black, red and gold. The card presumably predates the USA joining the war. There were several [other Allied countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allies_of_World_War_I) at various times.

Comment: Was Japan's flag in this era not red and white (or yellow and red for Imperial Japan)?

Comment: Red disc on white field for Japan itself, gold chrysanthemum on red field for the Emperor and variations for members of the Imperial House, red disc with red rays on white field for the Army and Navy (not the same design, but the same colours).